# Cocoapod spec: Unable to find other source ref for `Contents.json`

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to add my Assets.xcassets into my pod, so I have added the following to my podspec

```
      s.source_files     = ['Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift,json,strings,xib,storyboard}']
      s.resource_bundles = {'mysystem' => 'Classes/Resources/Assets.xcassets'}
```

I keep getting this error after I do pod lib lint

```
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find other source ref for `Contents.json` for target `mysystem`.) during validation.
```

Here is what it looks like inside of my resources folder

[image]

I have tried a lot of different other things instead but none worked:

1. I replaced resources_bundles with

```
      s.resources = ['Classes/Resources/Assets.xcassets']
```

2. I have also added xcassets to my source files

```
     s.source_files     = ['Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift,json,strings,xib,storyboard, xcassets}']
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the exact same error. The solution is,

Move the assets from Source to it's parent folder.

**Project Structure**

[image]

**And the podspec looks like this**

```
s.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'

  s.source_files = 'Source/**/**'
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
  s.platforms = {
    "ios": "13.0"
  }
  
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MotionToastView' => ['MotionToastView/**']
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this error can occur is that this `Contents.json` sits somewhere in source folder (that we specify in `.podspec` file).

You should double check that your source folder includes only code and nothing else.